# SQL Server calculate days from current date excluding days from another table

Tags: sql-server, date

I am trying to write a query that allows me to take the following table:

```
| Username | Startdate | Points |
|----------|-----------|--------|
| XXY      | 15-03-18  |      0 |
| YYX      | 12-02-18  |      1 |
| ZZY      | 10-06-18  |      2 |
```

and calculate days from current day excluding the days in table 2 that a user has been absent.

```
| Username | Startdate | Enddate  |
|----------|-----------|----------|
| XXY      | 20-03-18  | 25-03-18 |
```

Also another question, I need both tables to have a row for each day until current date. How do I do it?

Update: I have tried this in table 1 DATEDIFF(DAY, Startdate,GETDATE()) this gives me the amount of days. But I need to subtract 5 days from this (see table 2)

Comment: Can you include an example of the code you've currently tired?

Comment: Hi Tomos, I added more info

Comment: No offense, but that data and result are extremely confusing. They seem to be unrelated. `Username: XXY` goes from `Startdate: 15-03-18` to `Startdate: 02-03-18`. What is the relationship here? Also, what would your assumed calculation field look like in the situation of your results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
datediff(day, table1.StartDate, getdate()) - datediff(day, table2.StartDate, table2.Enddate)
from table1 
join table2 on table1.Username = table2.Username
```

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to do the below:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE Dates (SkipDate date);
GO

INSERT INTO Dates
VALUES ('20180605'),('20180617');
GO

WITH VTE AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(date,S) StartDate, CONVERT(date, E) EndDate
    FROM (VALUES('20180601','20180606'),
                ('20180601','20180618')) V(S,E))
SELECT StartDate,
       EndDate,
       DATEDIFF(DAY, StartDate, EndDate) AS DaysBetween,
       DATEDIFF(DAY, StartDate, EndDate) - SkipDates AS DaysMinusSkipped
FROM VTE
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) AS SkipDates
                  FROM Dates
                  WHERE SkipDate >= StartDate
                    AND SkipDate <= EndDate) AS SD;
GO
```

If you wanted to create something that means you don't need to write that SQL everytime instead, you can create a table-value function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DateDiffSkip (@StartDate date, @EndDate date)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN

    SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) - COUNT(SkipDate) AS DateDiffSkip
    FROM Dates D
    WHERE D.SkipDate >= @StartDate
      AND D.SkipDate <=  @EndDate;

GO
```

Then, your SQL would be:

```
WITH VTE AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(date,S) StartDate, CONVERT(date, E) EndDate
    FROM (VALUES('20180601','20180606'),
                ('20180601','20180618')) V(S,E))
SELECT StartDate,
       EndDate,
       DATEDIFF(DAY, StartDate, EndDate) AS DaysBetween,
       DDS.DateDiffSkip AS DaysMinusSkipped
FROM VTE
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DateDiffSkip(StartDate, EndDate) DDS;
GO
--Clean up
DROP FUNCTION DateDiffSkip;
DROP TABLE Dates;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be calculated with multiple DATEDIFF functions. This also calculates for multiple absences per user:

```
declare @t table ([UserName] char(3), [StartDate] Date, [Points] int)
insert into @t values ('XXY', '2018-03-15', 0), ('YYX', '2018-02-12', 1), ('ZZY', '2018-06-10', 2)

declare @a table ([UserName] char(3), [StartDate] Date, [EndDate] Date)
insert into @a values ('XXY', '2018-03-20', '2018-03-25')

select t.*, datediff(d, t.[StartDate], cast(getdate() as date)) - isnull(sum(datediff(d, a.[StartDate], a.[EndDate])), 0) as [DaysNotAbsent]
from @t t
left join @a a on t.UserName = a.UserName
group by t.UserName, t.StartDate, t.Points
```